# check folder and sub-folder sizes

Tags: powershell

I am kind of new to PowerShell. When my disk gets full several times and I have to clean it manually. I tried to create a PowerShell script which can tell me which folder is consuming more than 10gb with its location.

I used this -

```
$Directory = 'C:' 
$FilesAndFolders =Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Depth 2 
Foreach ($FileOrFolder in $FilesAndFolders) { 
    if ($FileOrFolder.Attributes -contains "Directory") { 
        #This is a folder - calculate the total folder size 
        $Length = (Get-ChildItem $FileOrFolder.FullName -Recurse | 
            Where-Object {$_.Attributes -notcontains "Directory"} | 
                Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length).Sum 
        $FileOrFolder | Select-Object Name, FullName, @{Name="Length"; Expression={$Length}} 
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is not clear if there is a question or problem to solve.

Comment: its an  problem to solve

Answer (score 1):

Your current code gives you bytes. You  have to do a `(Get-ChildItem C:\Directory | Measure-Object -Property Length -sum)  /1Gb` to convert the value to GB. Also - Force to look for hidden or system files

Answer (score 0):

I have similar things here.  'dus' outputs folders under the current directory sorted by size, and 'siz' outputs files.  Then you can cd down a folder and run them again.  It's based on unix aliases I used to have.  I put them in my $profile.

```
function com { param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
  [int64]$number)
  process { '{0:n0}' -f $number } }

function dus($dir=".") { 
  get-childitem -force -directory $dir -erroraction silentlycontinue -attributes !reparsepoint | 
    foreach { $f = $_ 
      get-childitem -force -r $_.FullName  -attributes !reparsepoint -ea 0 | 
        measure-object -property length -sum -erroraction silentlycontinue | 
        select @{Name="Name";Expression={$f}},Sum} | sort Sum |
    select name,@{n='Sum';e={$_.sum | com}}
}

function siz() {
  ls -file -force | select name,length | 
    sort length |
    select name,@{n='Length';e={$_.length | com}}
}
```